# Error in GraphQL where clause on Keystone 6

Tags: graphql, keystonejs

I am using Keystone 6, which ships with the latest version of Apollo. Normally, with GraphQL, we could insert a simple where clause with the following statement:

```
query {
  posts ( where: { title: "test" } ) {
    title
  }
}
```

However, upon trying this with Apollo Studio, I get the following error:

```
Expected value of type "StringFilter", found "test".
```

I have tried various ways to fix this but nothing seems to work. Can any of you help out?

Thank you.

Comment: implementation specific, check docs/specs for this api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I know that error. Keystone 6 is in a pre-release period and there are still occasional breaking changes to the API. Recently some changes to the structure of the GraphQL schema were [released](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/releases/tag/2021-08-17). Running the older style of queries on the new GraphQL schema will produce the error you're seeing.

In this case, the query can be rewritten as:

```
query {
  posts ( where: { title: { equals: "test" } } ) {
    title
  }
}
```

The [GraphQL Queries](https://keystonejs.com/docs/guides/filters#scalar-filters) docs have more usage instructions and examples. There's also an [upgrade guide](https://keystonejs.com/updates/new-graphql-api) that specifically covers all the changes you'll need to make to your queries from before this upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. It is unfortunate how long it took me to find out. Somehow I did not stumble upon those keystone documents, thank you for bringing them to my attention.

Comment: Is there a reason why the filtering patterns described in GraphQL docs do not work in Keystone? I mean, some rationale, explanation... This kinda makes trivial queries more complicated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @JindrichVavruska? The filtering patterns described in the Keystone docs work fine, the problem above is due to breaking changes early in KS6's development. If you're asking about the need to have `title: { equals: "test" }` rather than just `title: "test"`, this pattern lets Keystone support other comparison operators more cleanly (eg. `title: { gt: "test" }`. The alternative – having permutations for each field, eg. `title_gt`, `title_gte`, `title_contains`, etc. – significantly bloats the GraphQL schema. With the current pattern, the filter input type can be reused.

Comment: Hi, @Molomby, you are right. I was using Keystine API browser to play with some queries following GraphQL docs and not reading the Keystone docs. When I do it according to Keystone docs, everything works fine :)